# What is this 'hammer'?

Tags: discussion, support

I'm sure that at some point I knew this, but I have forgotten now, and can't remember how to remember, so I thought that I would ask, what exactly is the `mod-hammer`, and what does it mean to `give someone the hammer`? I hear these phrases thrown around a lot in the chat rooms, but I'm not really sure exactly what they mean...

Comment: The [PHP hammer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7xOy3.png) for SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/302251

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most versatile tool of all, the [hammer](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hammer) has quite a few English idioms attached to it.  Depending on the context, it might be to smite them or to explain the same thing over and over...

This question is a better fit for [the English SE](http://english.stackexchange.com).

<sub>*I* 'm teaching *you* English now???</sub>  **:P**

Answer (score 3):

I usually don't use google searches in answers, but when I do : https://www.google.com/search?q=giant+hammer&source=lnms&tbm=isch

It is simply a visualization of the what mods can do.

But yeah, it is they tools they have as mods have to kick, ban, smash, delete, or otherwise rend watermelon into pieces.